# Is there a way to show firebase notifications in the foreground on android and ios using ionic?

Tags: firebase, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I solved this problem in android studio by creating my custom notification handler and just inputing the data firebase sends. But I can't seem to find a way/guide/tutorial to do so with ionic.

Is there a way to do that or do is it only possible to show notifications when app in background?

I've tried every guide I found online but most of them just do nothing or the notification is just showed when app in background.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Update: 23 July 2019**
The reworked implementation has been released as `cordova-plugin-firebasex@6.0.0`.
See the documentation for more info: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase

**Original answer**
This is something I'm working on in [cordova-plugin-firebasex](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase) (my fork of [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase)).

Currently it's a work in progress (first draft implementation done for Android on the [dev branch](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase/tree/dev)) and I'm working on the iOS implementation.
You can test it out using [the dev branch of my test harness project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase-test/tree/dev).

Hoping to have a releasable version in the next week or so.

Comment: Hi Dave, just wondering about the release you mentioned in your comment. Is it released yet or are you still working on it?
Thanks!